# Python request response is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

My code below successfully pulled data from https://permit.pcta.org/application/

```
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate
import time

'''outputs '''
PERMITS = []

'''input'''
url = 'https://permit.pcta.org/manage/ajax/onload-ajax.php'


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

However, the response is empty. I am positive I didn't change anything in my code, so I can't explain why the website's response is now different.

As a sanity check below are snippets of the element and response from my browser.

[html element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEpi0.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBu2J.png)

Comment: What is your question?  Hitting that URL returns a 404 for me.

Comment: why the code I copied is not working anymore. The URL works, just tried it.

Comment: Did you tried to specify an Accept header with Application/JSON value?

Comment: Just tried that. I get the same error mentioned above.

Comment: One reason is you may use post method to get data. And the another reason should be login required before access

Comment: @stovfl I don't belive so.. the question isn't about json decoding. r.text and r.content are empty so there is nothing to parse. It's more about something that may be off in my requests.get()

Comment: *" isn't about json decoding. r.text and r.content are empty"*: If you already know this, [edit] your Question and **remove** all `json` related parts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the `Referer` in the headers, I added Referer to your code and it worked:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://permit.pcta.org/application/'
}
```

Not sure why it worked without it before, probably an api has changed, or you were passing Referer somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I found this out earlier by copying every header my browser used to make the request. Still not sure how it was working before without the Referer header.